How do I resolve the reading error with fuse-t-sshfs on macOS?
I am trying use sshfs with fuse-t on Sonoma. I just installed fuse-t and sshfs using brew (instructions here).
My system's configuration is as follows:
% uname -a
Darwin <device_name> 23.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 23.6.0: Mon Jul 29 21:13:04 PDT 2024; root:xnu-10063.141.2~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T6020 arm64

I ran the following command:
% sshfs -d -o allow_other,defer_permissions <remote_user>@<remote_host>:/home/<remote_user>/ ~/r/<remote_host>/
FUSE library version: 2.9.9
nullpath_ok: 0
nopath: 0
utime_omit_ok: 0
<remote_user>@<remote_host> password: 
unique: 2, opcode: INIT (26), nodeid: 0, insize: 56, pid: 0
INIT: 7.18
flags=0xfe00007b
max_readahead=0x00000000
   INIT: 7.19
   flags=0x00000011
   max_readahead=0x00000000
   max_write=0x02000000
   max_background=0
   congestion_threshold=0
   unique: 2, success, outsize: 40
fuse: mount failed with errro: -1
fuse: reading error: Bad file descriptor
^C

I have tried it with 3 different remote filesystems (all linux), none seem to work. I tried a reinstall as well, didn't work. I verified that I own the remote directory and have full permissions.
Am I missing something?
